# Сказуемое "Просил пить" - составное глагольное или с простое с дополнением?

Tags: грамматика

*Ещё одна старая моя головоломка, вспомнилась по ассоциации с другим вопросом.*

Рассуждаю.

*Хотел пить* - СГС.
*Хотел просить* -СГС.
*Дал пить* - объектный инфинитив, дополнение.
*Просил дать* - объектный инфинитив, дополнение.
Все так?

Тогда:

*Просил пить* - ?
*Просил дать пить* - ?

И наконец, *"Просил (себя) дать (себе) пить"*?!

Ну или, если последнее слишком умозрительно: *"Просил (себя) успокоиться и дать (себе) поспать"* - это уже вполне реально в некотором контексте. Получается, школьное определение отличия СГС от объектного инфинитива явно дает трещину.

Comment: Есть статья Чупашевой О. М. "Определяем синтаксическую функцию инфинитива", возможно, она поможет Вам найти ответ на вопрос. Ссылка: http://russkayarech.ru/files/issues/1999/1/19-chupasheva.pdf

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрел. Правда это "слишком школьный" уровень. Я хоть и дилетант голимый, но вопросы-то ставлю в расчете на дискуссию, а не на устранение пробелов в образовании.

Answer (score 2):

```
 школьное определение отличия СГС от объектного инфинитива явно дает   трещину.
```

А о каком определении идёт речь? Главное отличие в семантике, в лексическом значении, т.е. в вопросе к члену предложения.

Просил (о чём? что?)пить - дополнение. Просил (о чём?)дать пить - дополнение.
Дополнение, выраженное инфинитивом, принято отличать от части СГС, разграничивая  субъектный инфинитив и  объектный:Начинаю рассказывать, могу рассказать,  хотел пить – велел рассказать, просил рассказать, просил пить, просил дать пить.Инфинитив-дополнение обладает собственным лексическим значением. **В нём  нет ни модального, ни фазисного значения, в отличие от СГС**. Деятели глаголами обозначены разные. Такие дополнения – это объектный инфинитив.

**В качестве дополнения может выступать и субъектный инфинитив**, когда субъект обозначенного дополнением действия совпадает с субъектом действия поясняемого глагола: мы договорились(о чём?) переписываться. У Вас в последнем примере именно это и имеется.
*Просил себя (о чём?) успокоиться и (о чём?)дать (себе) поспать" -однородные дополнения.*

Comment: Людмила, под "школьным" определением, из-за которого вопрос, собственно, и возник я понимаю следующее. сочатание "личная форма + инфинитив" есть сказуемое плюс дополнение, если  а) действие личного глагола и инфинитива выполняются разными субъектами или б) глагол в личной форме не имеет ни фазисного, ни модального, ни вспомогательного значения. Иначе это - СГС (ну или аналитическая форма будущего времени). У нас просит и пьет одно и то же лицо. Значит, отказывая сочетанию "просил пить"  в статусе СГС, вы считаете, что "просил" начисто лишен модального значения. Я в этом-то крепко сомневаюсь.

Comment: Начисто или нет, но к модальным глаголам не относится. Модальные глаголы -глаголы со значением возможности, долженствования, желания, т.е. глаголы, выражающие отношение говорящего к содержанию высказывания. Мочь, долженствовать, уметь,хотеть, желать, намереваться, пытаться, стараться, надеяться, затеять и др. А "просить" - это "обращаться к кому-нибудь с просьбой  ", здесь нет оценки, это реальное действие.

Answer (score 1):

Вы ничего не путаете?

Смотрите, "просил папу" и "просил шоколадку" - это принципиально **разные** значения винительного падежа при глаголе "просить". Вы их, похоже, смешиваете. Второй случай допускает использование объектного инфинитива "просить дать", первый - максимум субъектного "просил пить", и то весьма проблематичного. Т.е. в первом варианте еще можно разглядеть какое-то подобие СГС, во втором - никак нельзя. Если это принять к сведению и не переносить свойства одного случая на другой, никаких сложностей с классификацией не возникает.

Ну а то, что сон там сам себя просит - это уже детали. Тут важно не физическое лицо, которое в реале может совпадает и даже не грамматическое (которое первое, второе и третье), а **синтаксическая роль** - подлежащее и дополнение, даже если они один и тот же субъект-объект обозначают.

Comment: Занятно... Никогда не задумывался. Не могу сразу вот так взять и согласиться. Но все-так что-то в этом есть, согласен. Т.е. Вы хотите сказать, что "просить пить" и просить "дать (пить)" - это разные грамматически конструкции, поскольку соответствуют разным семантическим (или семантико-синтаксическим) структурам?